# Customizing a default indentation style for C++

Tags: indentation, c++

I use the default style linux ([snippet from here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Custom-C-Indent.html))

```
;; set indentation style linux for c++
(setq c-default-style "linux"
          c-basic-offset 4)
```

But I can't get it to work with the style setting which sets zero indent for namespaces ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619853/emacs-override-indentation))

```
(defconst my-cc-style
  '("cc-mode"
    (c-offsets-alist . ((innamespace . [0])))))

(c-add-style "my-cc-mode" my-cc-style)
```

Once I choose my-cc-style with `C-c . RET my-cc-mode RET`, I get the strange brace indent back which the first setting removes, i.e. like this:

```
virtual string_type do_falsename() const
    {
```

Is there a way to keep everything from the default style, and change only the namespace indentation?

---

Edit: there are a multiple possible solutions to be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619853/emacs-override-indentation/22711444#22711444

Comment: I also had a hard time making this work, so now I just use a hook (added to `c-mode-common-hook`) that calls `(c-set-offset 'innamespace 0)`. Let me know if I should explain this in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining your style based on linux instead of cc-mode should help.

```
(defconst my-cc-style
 '("linux" ; this is inheritance from the linux style
   (c-offsets-alist . ((innamespace . [0])))))
```